# Can the complement of a subset of $[0,1]$ that has $>0$ measure be dense in $[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $C\subset[0,1]$ has measure $\epsilon>0$. Can $[0,1]\backslash C$ be dense in $[0,1]$?

I'm thinking of a Cantor like set, where the construction of the set is a series of removals of $2^{k-1}$ intervals of length $\epsilon\cdot 2^{-2k+1}$

Comment: the rationals are measure zero and are dense, so the anwer is yes, take C as the irrationals. You could construct $C$ to be measure $\epsilon$ by setting $C = [0,\epsilon]\cap \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Relevant Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set